# In an XSD schema, how do I say that an element might have any number of subelements that must inherit from a certain type?

Tags: xsd

Say I have these types defined in my XSD:

```
<complexType name="NamedEntity">
    <attribute name="ix" type="positiveInteger"></attribute>
    <attribute name="sName" type="string"></attribute>
    <attribute name="txtDesc" type="string"></attribute>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Node">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:NamedEntity">
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Source">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:NamedEntity">
            <attribute name="dt" type="dateTime"></attribute>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Now I want to express that a `Node` element may have zero or more child elements that may be of the type `Node` or `Source`.

It would be OK if I had to somehow enumerate the allowed types for the children, but since I have more types that inherit from `NamedEntity`, it would be neat if I could specify just the base type.

***Edit:*** I'd rather not use `xsi:type` in the document but have a unambigous relationship between element name and type. Quite a lot XML processing seems to depend on that, and I also find it a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* use `xsi:type` if you can avoid it. It's [evil](http://blog.whatfettle.com/2006/11/29/xsitype-is-evil/). Ok, maybe I exaggerate, but it does make it impossible to parse the document without *intimate* knowledge of the schema, which is bad enough in practice.

What *will* help you is: [`substitutionGroup`](http://www.xfront.com/ElementHierarchy.html).

Comment: Cool - learn something new every day :-). I'll bear that in mind for the future.

Comment: However, this is not supported well by JAXB. When generating classes for the XML element types, child elements are mapped to `JAXBElement<T extends AbstractType>` rather than to `T`

Answer (score 0):

In the schema, have the `Node` element contain zero or more child elements of type `NamedEntity`. In the actual document, use the `xsi:type` attribute (`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`) to choose the subtype (`"Node"` or `"Source"`) for each one.

Comment: I'd rather not use xsi:type, will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be beyond the capabilities of XSD. Have you considered doing extra validation using [Schematron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [substitution group](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_subst.asp).